# What's the differnce between canny and contour in opencv?

Tags: algorithm, opencv

I am new to opencv and I don't know much about the algorithms. I just downloaded opencv and tried to run the samples. One thing I noticed that both canny and contour can be used to find the objects, from opencv official docs:

Canny:

> Finds edges in an image using the [Canny86] algorithm.

findContours:

> Finds contours in a binary image.

I think they have similar functionalities, so what are the differences between them and how to choose? And please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about image processing, but has nothing to do with programming. This would be  better asked on http://answers.opencv.org/

Comment: @Aurelius Questions on OpenCV are not off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important practical difference is that findContours gives connected contours, while Canny just gives edges, which are lines that may or may not be connected to each other.   To choose, I suggest that you try both on your sample application and see which gives better results.